# HTML <a> tag to Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think there is a relative easy answer to this, but how can I make this `link_to`...:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(p.thumbnail, class: "hoi"), "Something in here?") %>
```

...link to the same as this:

```
<a class="fg" href="#<%= p.id %>" data-toggle="modal">
```

?

(Just to be clear: When I click on the image in the `link_to`, I want to get linked to `href="#<%= p.id %>"` with the `data-toggle="modal"` option).

Comment: you want to literally see `#<%= p.id %>"` as the value for the href element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to link an image to an anchor on the page, do this:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(p.thumbnail, class: "hoi"), "##{p.id}") %>
```

You can do normal ruby string interpolation inside erb block (`<%= %>`)

Comment: Hehe I see it now (I tried to put this `#<%= p.id %>` inside a `<%= %>` block, that was the reason I didn`t make it). Thanks! I ended up with this: `<%= link_to(image_tag(p.thumbnail, class: "hoi"), "##{p.id}", "data-toggle" => "modal") %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to "##{p.id}", "Something in here?", :class => "fg", :data-toggle => "modal" %>
```